# Error when trying to add value labels to a column

Tags: r, label

I'm trying to add value labels to a column, `sex`:

```r
library(dplyr)

data_mch_new %>%
   mutate(sex = as.factor(x = sex,
                          levels = c(0, 1)
                          labels = c("Female", "Male")
                          ))
```

However, this leads to the following error :

> "Error in UseMethod("mutate") :
> no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "factor"

What is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share a ```dput(head(data_mch_new)) ``` of your data so we can help.

Comment: Try `factor(...)` instead of `as.factor()`

Comment: You're missing a comma after "levels". Also, "sex" is already a factor, so maybe you just need `levels(data_mch_new$sex)<-c("Female","Male")`.

Comment: The error message indicated that `data_mch_new` is not a data.frame. It seems to be a simple vector. If you expected it to be a data.frame, then something went wrong earlier in your code that you've not shown us.

Comment: structure(list(X = 1:6, SUB_NUM = 20161001:20161006, ga_months = c(9L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L), ga_weeks = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), smok_prego = c("yes", 
"1", "nodded", "0", "refused", "No "), sex = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    age = c(17L, 25L, 20L, 37L, 24L, 24L), smok_prego2 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame") @Benson_YoureFired

Comment: @MrFlick for your Reference "structure(list(X = 1:6, SUB_NUM = 20161001:20161006, ga_months = c(9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L), ga_weeks = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L), smok_prego = c("yes", "1", "nodded", "0", "refused", "No "), sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), age = c(17L, 25L, 20L, 37L, 24L, 24L), smok_prego2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 9L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: That's the value of `data_mch_new `? Because you should be getting a different error message then. Something is not adding up.